# How do I get my regex to return just my match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing this:

```
var regex = /^.*brainshark.*\/(?:vu\?pi=(.*)|.*-(\d*))/;

string.match(regex).exec()
```

Assuming the string matches the regex at all, I get back an array of three. The first element contains the entire string. The second element may or may not contain a match, and my third element may or may not contain a match.

Assuming my string is  "http://my.brainshark.com/Public-Speaking-For-Executives-409829042"
 my match will be on index 2.

If the string is "http://www.brainshark.com/cvi/vu?pi=zF0z1327H2zC5iGz0" , then the match will be on index 1

How can I get it so that my matches are always in element 1, or possibly, that I just get back my match without any array at all?

Comment: Just wonder why would you need to put all the logic into a single regexp? Why not use normal if statement or something? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version: In JavaScript... you can't.

But let's get some terminology straight first: The first item in the array is your actual **match**. You get the entire string back because your pattern happens to match the entire string. Then you get one item per **captured group** (the parentheses in your pattern).

JavaScript is, unfortunately, very limited in its regex support. Other flavors would let you get what you want easily. For instance:

- Perl/PCRE supports the [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html): `(?|vu\?pi=(.*)|.*-(\d*))` - this pattern would return a single capture group.
- .NET supports duplicate named groups: `(?:vu\?pi=(?<id>.*)|.*-(?<id>\d*))` - this pattern would return a single value in the `id` group.

But in JS you'll basically have to extract your value yourself. A simple solution would be:

```
var match = /your regex/.exec(yourString);
var value = match && (match[1] || match[2]);
```

---

As a side note, I'd rewrite your pattern like this:

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/]*?brainshark.*\/(?:vu\b.*?[?&]pi=([^&]*)|.*-(\d*))/i
```

I used `[^&]*` and `[?&]` for when you'll encounter an URL with more query arguments. The change at the beginning is to make sure the `brainshark` string is in the hostname. Oh, and I also added case insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining two capturing groups within an alternation which is not repeated. Therefore, either capturing group can match a substring, but **not both at the same time**. That explains why your match is sometimes found at index 1 (first capturing group) and sometimes at index 2 (second capturing group).

Basically, you have a couple of options:

1. Rewrite your regex so that there's only a single capturing group around the alternation.
2. Match your text against the existing expression and choose one of the two captured values.
3. Write two simpler expressions, check whether the first one matches, and if not, execute the second.

Here's how option #2 could look like:

```
var matches = string.match(regex);
var id = matches[1] || matches[2];
```

I would opt for option #1, though.